# Building Qt 5.6 on macOS for the Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: macos, qt, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I am trying to set up a cross compiling environment for the Raspberry Pi 3 on my Mac because compiling on the Pi just became to slow.

Following [this guide](http://www.jaredwolff.com/blog/cross-compiling-on-mac-osx-for-raspberry-pi/) I successfully created a cross compiler using `crosstool-ng` that is able to compile a simple `"Hello World"` program that runs on the Pi.

I try to follow the [RaspberryPi2EGLFS-Guide](https://wiki.qt.io/RaspberryPi2EGLFS) on the Qt wiki.
It is written for Ubuntu but that should not make a difference when you have a compiler for your host system, does it?

I created the sysroot and fixed symbolic links as described in the guide, but the configure command for Qt fails.

```
./configure \
 -release \
 -opensource -confirm-license \
 -make libs \
 -opengl es2 \
 -device linux-rpi3-g++ \
 -sysroot $SYSROOT \
 -opensource -confirm-license -make libs \
 -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/dev/raspi/qt5pi \
 -hostprefix ~/dev/raspi/qt5 \
 -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=$TOOLCHAIN \
 -v
```

There, `$TOOLCHAIN` points to the toolchain I compiled and `$SYSROOT` is the sysroot I set up according to the guide.

But the command fails with a bunch of errors because header files could not be found:

```
fatal error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
fatal error: zconf.h: No such file or directory
fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory
```

---

**Edit 12-14-2016**

Apparently the compiler can't determine the cpu architecture:

```
/Volumes/xtools/armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/lib/gcc/armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/5.2.0/../../../../armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.gold: error: /Volumes/xtools/armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/armv8-rpi3-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr/lib/crti.o: unknown CPU architecture
```

---

From my (limited) understanding, these headers should apear somewhere in `$SYSROOT`.
I have checked my sysroot, the missing headers a located in `$SYSROOT/usr/include/arm-arm-linux-gnueabihf/`.
I created a symlink from there to `$SYSROOT/sys` but that did not work either.
Am I missing something?
[Other threads](https://askubuntu.com/a/725965) suggest installing `g++-multilib` on the host system, but there is no multlib-equivalent on macOS.